# Define a function that returns most common words for a period of time using Python

Tags: python, pandas, function, date, datetime

I am working with a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    text                    senders date                   words    characters
0   esta muy bueno          L       2018-03-14 17:00:00    4        20
1   congratz                L       2018-03-14 17:00:00    1        8
2   en la tarde instalamos  L       2018-03-14 17:00:00    5        28
3   muy bueno eso..         G       2018-03-14 17:00:00    5        28
4   asi voy a hacer         G       2018-03-14 17:00:00    9        39
5   jajaja                  L       2018-03-14 17:00:00    1        6
6   jajajajajajaj           G       2018-03-14 17:16:00    1        13
7   lucho                   G       2018-03-14 17:33:00    1        5
8   ah no                   G       2018-03-14 17:33:00    2        5
9   nonono                  G       2018-03-14 17:33:00    1        6
```

What I want to do is to define a function that returns the number of times a certain word in the `text` column was used by each of the `senders` (L or G) during a certain period of time. Is this posible? The data go from March, 2018 to December, 2018.

I have already written a piece of code which returns the most common words in the `text` column:

```
from collections import Counter 
words = '' for i in df.text.values: 
    words += '{} '.format(i.lower()) #make words lowercase 
pd.DataFrame(Counter(words.split()).most_common(20), columns=['word', 'frequency'])
```

Also, the `date` column has already been turned into datatime with:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible, please show what you have tried from your research. Have you converted the column to datetimes? Have you tried grouping by time intervals?

Comment: I have used `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` to turn the `date` column into datetime.

Comment: Also, I wrote this piece of code to count most common words but for the whole `df`: `from collections import Counter
words = ''
for i in lucho.text.values:
    words += '{} '.format(i.lower()) #make words lowercase

pd.DataFrame(Counter(words.split()).most_common(20), columns=['word', 'frequency'])`

Comment: Please [edit] that into your original question with correct formatting

Comment: @roganjosh I just don't know how to put everything together: period of time, a certain word, and the count of that word for each `sender`

Comment: @roganjosh done.

Comment: Try making a dictionary with the words and their number of occurrences?

Comment: How would you do it? @Riker

Comment: This wouldn't solve the time bit, but you should be able to loop over the lines and add each word. If it's in the dictionary, add 1 to its value, otherwise make it and set to 1.